# Slice a string from second space to a special character?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var name_RawString = 'A. John Doe-John (Class of 2010)';
```

I'm trying to extract a substring occuring after the second space and before `(`. In this case: "Doe-John".

So far I've tried:

```
var GetStr = name_RawString.slice(name_RawString.substr(0, name_RawString.indexOf(' ', name_RawString.indexOf(' ') + 1)), name_RawString.indexOf(' ('));
```

and

```
var StrSplit = name_RawString.split(' ');
var GetStr = name_RawString.slice(name_RawString.indexOf(StrSplit[1]) + 1)), name_RawString.indexOf(' ('));
```

Comment: your string value is always the same?

Comment: no, this would be used in a conditional statement for strings where `StrSplit[0].indexOf('.')>-1`

Comment: proib this ( var name_RawString = 'A. John Doe-John (Class of 2010)';
var space=name_RawString.split(' ');
console.log(space[1]+" "+space[2]); )

Answer (score 0):

You could give regular expressions a try:

```
name_RawString.match(/^(?:\S+\s){2}(.+?) \(/)[1];
```

Or, if You prefer a more verbose solution:

```
var haystack = 'A. John Doe-John (Class of 2010)';

var firstSpaceIndex = haystack.indexOf(' ');
var secondSpaceIndex = haystack.indexOf(' ', firstSpaceIndex + 1);
var openParenIndex = haystack.indexOf('(');

var needle = haystack.slice(secondSpaceIndex + 1, openParenIndex - 1);
```